# Variance of maximum of random variables with finite second moment

Tags: variance

How to deduce the following general result:
$$ \operatorname{Var}(\max_i X_i) \leq \sum_i \operatorname{Var}(X_i)\,,$$
where $X_1,\dots,X_N$ are any random variables (maybe not independent) with finite second moment.

I have seen this result many times, but I don't know how to prove it. Thank you for your help.